# What is placeholder_token in html.html.twig for?

Tags: 8, theming

Started to dive into Drupal 8 twig, and what better place to start than from the top:  [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!html.html.twig/8)

But found this:

```
<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
```

Here is the change record:

- [#2565021: HTML template head, scripts, styles and scripts_bottom replaced with placeholder_token](https://www.drupal.org/node/2565021)

And some related issues:

- [#2538950: Replace SafeMarkup::format() in template_preprocess_html with placeholders in the template](https://www.drupal.org/node/2538950)
- [#2603074: Remove |raw from use in core templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603074)

And the documentation:

- [html.html.twig on api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!html.html.twig/8)

But nothing really clarifies why this was done.

Is this a Drupalism? A Twigism? What are these tokens for?

The only other time I've seen a placeholder token system like this was with CTools where they create a placeholder in the generated HTML output and then go back later and replace the token with the actual value.  If this is the same concept, why does Drupal core need to do this? (The CTools system was ostensibly to get around some core limitations).

Comment: here are some more pieces to the puzzle [HTML template head, scripts, styles and scripts_bottom replaced with placeholder_token](https://www.drupal.org/node/2565021) and [placeholder_token: The token for generating head, css, js and js-bottom placeholders.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!html.html.twig/8)

Comment: Thanks, I just found the change record on my own.  But neither there nor the second link you provided explain what's going on.

Comment: yes, that's why I provided them as a comment rather than an answer to a good question.

Comment: I've a response from Joel Pittet on Twitter (https://twitter.com/joelpittet/status/667930798625046528) stating that this change was related to the new Page Cache system pioneered by Wim Leers.  I think to mark an answer as the accepted answer, it would need to elaborate on this information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why placeholder_token is used in html.html.twig instead of using just a normal variable is that in Drupal 8 we have different render strategies than just the simple rendering where everything gets rendered in the template and we are able to collect the assets.

In the Drupal cores default Renderer we have [placeholders](https://www.drupal.org/node/2498803) (placeholders might attach some additional assets). If we would print the assets in a normal variable it would happen before all the assets have been collected. So what Drupal 8 does is it first renders everything with the normal rendering in the template, then it replaces the placeholders and collects assets from then, and after all that has been done we finally replace the asset placeholders to add the assets to the page.

Comment: This is pretty insightful. Thanks.  Lauriii do you know if there is a new workflow diagram of the HTML building and rendering process for Drupal 8?

Comment: There is actually diagram and more info available here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/pipeline

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:**   In a practical scenario `<head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` == `{{ head }}`

The issue where this change was introduced is:
[Move attachment processing to services and per-type response subclasses](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407195)

And like this [change record says](https://www.drupal.org/node/2565021) this:

```
 <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
```

Just replace this:

```
{{ head }}
```

The token attribute is just for avoid collisions it doesn't have any other special purpose.

You can see at Theme.inc at the function `template_preprocess_html` the following code:

```
$types = [
  'styles' => 'css',
  'scripts' => 'js',
  'scripts_bottom' => 'js-bottom',
  'head' => 'head',
];
$variables['placeholder_token'] = Crypt::randomBytesBase64(55);
foreach ($types as $type => $placeholder_name) {
  $placeholder = '<' . $placeholder_name . '-placeholder token="' . 
  $variables['placeholder_token'] . '">';
  $variables['#attached']['html_response_attachment_placeholders'][$type] = $placeholder;
}
```

Which basically builds all the tokens and put them in the `html_response_attachment_placeholders` array.

Later when the page is being rendered the tokens are replaced by the data (scripts,styles etc) see `HtmlResponseAttachmentsProcessor::processAttachments`

Comment: "The token attribute is just for avoid collisions it doesn't have any other special purpose."  To avoid collisions with what, exactly?

Comment: With any other  placeholder_name that could be added in the future or in a different theme, this was discussed [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407195#comment-9962395) and added to the code [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407195#comment-9973397) and FabianX mention to all the place holders are now unique  [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2407195#comment-9973725)

Comment: If you need to change what is output here, that's configuration or code.  You can of course *add* things that you'd normally add in your `<head>` section directly in your theme's `html.html.twig` file, if they don't need to obey any caching rules.  So for instance you could disable the Favicon element in your theme settings and then paste in an expanded set of favicon-related links and meta tags here.