# Filter |raw doesn't show entity media image

Tags: 8, media

Using the following code for displaying content from a WYSIWYG field:
`content.field_body|raw` I only got the text without images added in a editor as media. When I remove filter raw I see `<drupal-entity data-embed-button="media_browser" data-entity-embed....` is being displayed as a text but not as image.

Comment: This happens in paragraph, I forgot to mention.

Comment: probably the text filter for embedded media is missing, check if "Display embedded entities" is checked in the text format configuration

Comment: "Display embedded entities" is checked in rich text configuration.

Comment: then you need to make sure that the text format is applied to the field, it seems it is not

Comment: @4k4 how can I check that?

Comment: if you have a body field in another place, such as in a content type, that works normally, you could compare what is different

Comment: @4k4 If I use text long field in content type works correctly, if I use text long field in paragraph component it doesn't show.

Comment: why would you use |raw on content.field_body? I'd recommend you include the whole template. Are the paragraph and node using the same text format?

Comment: @Berdir I want to show the content from that field in a div, I don't want to show the whole paragraph because of my HTML structure.

Comment: This may be related with the issue. I have a paragraph Accordion that contains another paragraph for accordion items as a child. The content from that child elements is not displaying correctly.

Comment: `content.field_tabs[0]` returns the whole paragraphs with all fields, content body field is called **field_content** and when I try to access to its full content with the following `content.field_tabs[0]['#paragraph'].field_content` got only the text from the body field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This output from the body field

```
<drupal-entity data-embed-button="media_browser" data-entity-embed....
```

is the raw data stored in the database. The tag `<drupal-entity>` gets replaced by the text filter "Display embedded entities" when the field is rendered.

If you access the field data directly from the entity `#paragraph` you bypass this rendering process.

Instead of the raw filter, which doesn't help in any way, it only makes your site vulnerable to the content of the body field, you can apply the text format in a render element `processed_text`:

```
  {% set paragraph =  content.field_tabs.0['#paragraph'] %}

  {% set body = {
    '#type':   'processed_text',
    '#text':    paragraph.field_body.value,
    '#format':  paragraph.field_body.format,
  } %}

  {{ body }}
```

Comment: Right/Perfect/Satisfying approach and the Drupal way!

Comment: If someone looking to implement in the module file

`$quiz_summary = $node->get('field_paragraph')->referencedEntities();`

Field_paragraph is the name of paragraph field. Then get a preferable body field from paragraph.

`$score_summary = [
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $paragraph->get('field_summary_text')->getValue()[0]['value'],
    '#format' => $paragraph->get('field_summary_text')->getValue()[0]['format']
  ];`

Then use it like

`render($score_summary)`