# how to get field image of a referenced entity in paragraph template

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I made a paragraph with a referenced entity field to a content type called "tools"
Actually I can get the title and body text like that :

```
<h3>{{ content.field_tools_and_services.0['#node'].title.value }}</h3>
<p>{{ content.field_tools_and_services.0['#node'].body.value}}</p>
```

now, I need to get the field image, I tried to do something like this :

```
<img alt="{{ content.field_tools_and_service1[0]['#node'].field_image.get(0).alt }}"
src="{{ content.field_tools_and_service1[0]['#node'].field_image.entity.fileuri|image_style('image_format') }}"
title="{{ content.field_tools_and_service1[0]['#node'].field_image.get(0).title }}">

<img src="{{ content.field_tools_and_service1.0['#node'].values.field_image.0['#uri'] }}"
alt="{{ label.0 }}">

{{ content.field_tools_and_service1.0['#node'].field_image.value) }}
```

But I can't get my image, what's my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of doing that consider creating a new view mode for your referenced entity that just displays the fields you want (and also comes with its own template) and then simply choose the view mode for the referenced entities in the parent entity's display settings. No one should need to write image markup like that anymore.

Comment: I already did it with this way, but I wanted to try do it with paragraph, I'm new to drupal, and I would like to try to do this another way to train

Comment: Please don't post code examples with the `|raw` filter, this is extremely dangerous. If you can't use a view mode, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231805/filter-raw-doesnt-show-entity-media-image/231981#231981

Comment: Doing it "this way" is not a good way to train. Render things appropriately as leymannx said, that is worth learning over extended markup above.