# Modify "head-placeholder" in html.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

that's the first time I approach to Drupal or a CMS more generally but I've been working since years as FE dev.

I'm creating a theme based on a template created from scratch for the Italian Public Administration(PA) in such way to define a standard for the PA websites.

[This](https://github.com/italia-it/ita-web-toolkit) is the template project

So I have to fully rely over the CSS and JS files provided by the theme, and can't use a base theme.

I'm struggling to understand how to change the content of the `head-placehoder` and the `title` one in the `html.html.twig` file

```
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
  </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here by Google, if you want to change the meta tags or other things injected by `head-placeholder`, you can use `hook_page_attachments_alter()`. Here is an example where I have removed the meta tag for Generator in Drupal 8. This meta tag:

```
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)">
```

In your your_theme.theme, here is the code:

```
function your_theme_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
   foreach ($attachments["#attached"]["html_head"] as $key => $attachment) {
     if ('meta' === $attachment[0]["#tag"] &&
         !empty($attachment[0]["#attributes"]["name"]) &&
         'Generator' === $attachment[0]["#attributes"]["name"]) {

            unset($attachments["#attached"]["html_head"]["$key"]);
     }
   }
}
```

If you want to know about `header-placholder` and how the rendering is happening, read the accepted answer for this post [What is placeholder_token in html.html.twig for?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181594/what-is-placeholder-token-in-html-html-twig-for)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme, which provides pretty good documentation on how to add CSS in a theme.

If you don't extend from a theme then you technically extend from a special theme called "stable". You should get almost no default CSS then, at least from core modules. Unless that really results in a problem, in which case there are some options to override it (documented above), I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Actually this allows me to add CSS, but what i need is to modify the head-placeholder section like the <meta> tags

Comment: To add what kind of metatags exactly? You can either just hardcode them below/above in the template or you can add them through a hook like hook_page_attachments_alter(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913739/add-meta-tag-to-head-in-drupal-8

Comment: The question is 'Modify head-placeholder' not 'suggest best practice for placing css'. I want to modify the head placeholder for other reasons.